# Problem Install Python 3.12.1 - python returns an error on running

Tags: python-3.x, pip, centos7

Centos 7.9
I download Python-3.12.1.tgz and install it like this:

`./configure --enable-optimizations --with-openssl=/usr/bin/openssl`
`sudo make install`

The make returns this error:

```
./_bootstrap_python ./Programs/_freeze_module.py abc ./Lib/abc.py Python/frozen_modules/abc.h
Fatal Python error: init_import_site: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/admin_portal/Python-3.12.1/Lib/site.py", line 73, in <module>
    import os
  File "/home/admin_portal/Python-3.12.1/Lib/os.py", line 29, in <module>
    from _collections_abc import _check_methods
SystemError: <built-in function compile> returned NULL without setting an exception
make: *** [Python/frozen_modules/abc.h] Error 1
```

After installation, I run `/usr/local/bin/python3.12 -m pip`, I get the following error:

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Could not find platform dependent libraries <exec_prefix>
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = '/usr/local/bin/python3.12'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  safe_path = 0
  import site = 1
  is in build tree = 0
  stdlib dir = '/usr/local/lib/python3.12'
  sys._base_executable = '/usr/local/bin/python3.12'
  sys.base_prefix = '/usr/local'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/usr/local'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = '/usr/local/bin/python3.12'
  sys.prefix = '/usr/local'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/usr/local'
  sys.path = [
    '/usr/local/lib/python312.zip',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.12',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.12/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

Current thread 0x00007f8882742740 (most recent call first):

I have read about the env variables, and running unset PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH, made no difference, same error. I do have other version of python on the machine, 3.10, which is also broken, as it refuses to run pip

First tried to install Python 3.10.2 and I try to run pip, and it gets error:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3.10: No module named pip.__main__; 'pip' is a package and cannot be directly executed
```

So tried the newer version, and it is a different error. kind of stumped.
Any help/advice is very welcome!